# Regression with multiple categorical variable

Tags: regression, categorical-data

Goodmorning, I have cross sectional data and I want to make multiple regression. In my  model there are 5 categorical variable: Years, Sex, Maritial status, Education and Regions. Is it possible to regroup some of these variables in a single group of controls? I'm not interested to know the effect of such variables separately but only in term of fixed effect and I'm afraid that adding too many dummy variables separately would make the intrepretation of the results confusing.

Comment: If the variables are just then to control for their effect and you are not interested in them individually then why are you concerned about interpreting them?

Comment: I'm not intrested to interpret the effect of all categorical variable but I want to capture their effect for correctly specify the model.

Comment: In that case I am not sure what your problem is. Perhaps you could edit in some more details. What is your scientific question?

Comment: In order to fit the model I need to include severall independet variables which are categorical variable but I don't need to know the effect of those variables. I would like to put them toghether  as a group of control variables.

Comment: `local controls education Married region age^2`

`reg retric proxy1_t `controls' if  Condprof==1`

I used this code(on Stata), where "education" "Married" and "region" are dummy

Comment: Why do you think it is a problem? If problem is loss of degrees of freedom, maybe use regularization

Comment: sorry in class we didn't use regolarization so I don't know what do you mean,  the teacher said that model missing important infomation suffer from bias from under specification